# Управление фоновыми процессами через веб-интерфейс

Tags: php, linux

Ситуация: есть **Linux** сервер, доступ на который есть только через диал-ап из другого города за несколько тыс. км.

На этом сервере от n-го юзера работает процесс на **php** с зоопарком собственных форков.
Нужно видеть нагрузку, которую этот зверинец создаёт на систему, иногда перезапускать, какие-то моменты автоматизировать.

**SSH** сессия виснет и часто рвётся, **screen** не предлагать. Уверен, есть готовое решение, только не помню, как называется. Подскажите?

Comment: @timophey, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

[[@timophey](/users/8901/timophey)](/users/8901/timophey),

http://linuxdash.com/

Сам пока с ней не работал, но все должно быть ок.

**upd**
linuxdash вроде бы не умеет управлять процессами. В принципе для таких дел пользуют zabbix, но он вроде как не очень хорош в небольших масштабах; есть еще http://www.pulseway.com/features - но все, что я знаю о нем, это что у меня есть их приложение на десктопе.

Comment: @Etki, если уж ssh толком не работает, то почему Вы считаете, что этой штуке хватит ресурсов?

Comment: @avp, я так понял, что проблемы с ssh из-за расстояния и коннекта.

Comment: выглядит симпатично, но это только монитор, хоть и избыточный.
мне бы управление php демоном через браузер

Answer (score 1):

[monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) следит за демонами и прочими системными делами — можете сделать конфиги, чтобы перезапускать определённые процессы, если висят дольше, чем N, не отзываются и по прочим условиям.

См. [примеры конфигураций](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples), для представления о возможностях.

Answer (score 0):

http://supervisord.org/
http://habrahabr.ru/post/162039/